# in my case，i use aiomysql for my httpserver，but it raised a error，more details as fallow:

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGt1O.png)

i am searching for a long time on net. But not use. I have tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logging.info(' %s : has_request_arg = %s, has_var_kw_arg = %s, get_named_args = %s, get_required_kw_args = %s' % (
    __name, self._has_named_kw_args, self._named_kw_args, self._required_kw_args
))
```

You have 5 string placeholders for interpolation, but only supply 4 parameters to it. You need to ensure that the number of arguments matches the amount required to format the string.

Also, please in future copy the text of your stacktrace/code, and paste it, instead of supplying an image.